# How to view Specific files Inside a Folder in android?

Tags: android

I have created a folder in my android application in 
/sdcardhome/myImages

Now I have saved all my Images Inside that folder.
I am trying to browse that folder from my Android program but its Not working.

This is what I have tries so far

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MediaScannerConnectionClient{
public String[] allFiles;
private String SCAN_PATH ;
private static final String FILE_TYPE = "*/*";
private MediaScannerConnection conn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCameraApp"+File.separator+"Images");
    allFiles = folder.list();

    SCAN_PATH=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MyCameraApp/Images"+allFiles[0];
     startScan();
    }
    private void startScan(){
    if(conn!=null)
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, this);
    conn.connect();
}
@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    conn.scanFile(SCAN_PATH, FILE_TYPE);

}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
     try
     {
         if (uri != null) 
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setData(uri);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     }
     finally 
     {
         conn.disconnect();
         conn = null;
     }


    }
```

When I fire event from some view nothing open(Screen is there)
So How to make this to open all Images inside 
     /sdcardhome/MyCameraApp/Images?